# Django file object is closing when it moves out of function scope - Python3

Tags: django, python-3.6

I have a below django view

```
from io import TextIOWrapper

def get_header_data(file_obj):
    # perform some operations like
    text_file = TextIOWrapper(file_obj)
    reader = csv.reader(text_file)
    .....
    .....
    file_obj.seek(0)
    print(file_obj.closed, "--> Inside get_header_data method")
    return some_data

def upload(request):
    file_obj = request.FILES["file"]
    print(file_obj.closed, "--> Inside upload before entering in to get_header_data method")
    # Get some headers
    header_data = get_header_data(file_obj)
    # Facing an error at this point file_obj.seek(0)
    print(file_obj.closed, "--> Inside upload after returned from get_header_data method")
    file_obj.seek(0)
```

**Output**:

```
False--> Inside upload before entering in to get_header_data method
False--> Inside get_header_data method
True--> Inside upload after returned from get_header_data method
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file at line 5 (file_obj.seek(0)) inside upload method
```

The problem here is, in case of python3, the `file_obj` which I sent to `get_header_data` from `upload` method is getting closed by python when the interpreter moved out of upload function(when it got returned).

The same code is working fine in `Python 2.7`, so what could be the problem here and why the `file_obj` is getting closed when the interpreter moved out of `get_header_data` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextIOWrapper` object closes the underlying stream when it is destroyed (`__del__` method calls `close`). In your case, file object is closed because when you return from the `get_header_data` the `text_file` is destroyed.

You can use `detach` to separate the underlying raw stream from the buffer.

```
def get_header_data(file_obj):
    # perform some operations like
    text_file = TextIOWrapper(file_obj)
    .....
    .....
    text_file.detach()
    file_obj.seek(0)
    .....
```